# Fetch data from database and shift and add new value in an array

Tags: php, arrays, oracle10g

In database table I have Value column.Have more than 50 rows. Now in php, I have an fixed array of 10. at first 10 rows will be fetched from database and stored into array. When array will be full, and 11th value will try to insert into array , 0th value will move and 11th value will insert into the array. For example like QUEUE process.

At first it will show

```
[[0,17.9999],[1,13.898],...[9,16.98]]
```

then `[0,17.9999] will move and [10,11.88]` will insert and it will print as follow

```
[[1,13.898],.......[9,16.98],[10,11.88]]
```

then

```
[2,17.84],......[10,11.88],[11,999]]
```

and so on..

How can I represent it in php?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include("md.php");
$sql = "SELECT * from datatable";
$result =oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$r=oci_execute($result);
$arr = array();
$i=0;
while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC)){

  $arr[] = array_shift(array($i++, (float)$row['VALUE']));
}
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Please help.

Comment: What's the purpose of all this? take last 10 records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have 10 keys in array, try

```
 $arr=array_slice($arr,1,9);
 $arr[]=$row['VALUE'];
```

instead

```
$arr[] = array_shift(array($i++, (float)$row['VALUE']));
```

Note, It will be correct, when you already have array with 10 items. 
See example below

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
echo json_encode($arr)."<br>";    
$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','app_user2','qwe123','test');
$select="select id from adv where id > 300 and id < 312;";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $select);                      
while ($row=$res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $arr=array_slice($arr,1,9);
    $arr[]=$row['id'];
    echo json_encode($arr)."<br>";
}
```

In browser it would represented as

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"301"]
[3,4,5,6,7,8, 9,10,"301","302"]
[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"301","302","303"]
[5,6,7,8,9,10,"301","302","303","304"]
[6,7,8,9,10,"301","302","303","304","305"]
[7,8,9,10,"301","302","303","304","305","306"]
[8,9,10,"301","302","303","304","305","306","307"]
[9,10,"301","302","303","304","305","306","307","308"]
[10,"301","302","303","304","305","306","307","308","309"]
["301","302","303","304","305","306","307","308","309","310"]
["302","303","304","305","306","307","308","309","310","311"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, on 50 entries you'll get only 10, and the 11th is pushing away the 1st value of the array... It's like getting the last 10 resulsts, don't you think?

By admitting that your table has an auto-incremented 'id' field :

```
<?php
include("md.php");
// I've changed your SQL query by adding a reverse sort
// on the 'id' field and put a limit of 10 entries
$sql = "SELECT * from datatable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10";
$result =oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$r=oci_execute($result);
$arr = array();
$i=0;
while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)){
  $arr[] = (float)$row['VALUE'];
}
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

I haven't tested this snippet but it should work fine ;)

EDIT : Please ignore if Ilya's answer is what you want to do D: